# Separability of a field Extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f=x^n-1$, and $L$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $K$ .

Basically my question is to show that the extension $L|K$  is separable .

Here is what i have been thinking , If char $K =0$ then its clear that its separable while $f' \not=0. 
$
 similarly in the case when Char$K =p$ where $p \not|  n$.

But in the case when $p$ divides $n$ then we can write $n=p^km$ where $p\not|m$

then $x^n-1 =x^{p^km} -1 =(x^m-1)^{p^k}$ ie essentially the splitting field of $x^n-1$ is the splitting field of $x^m-1$, but splitting field of $x^m-1$ is separable with the 1st argument .

Now here is my doubt $x^n-1$ has $n$ solution , but $x^m-1$ has $m$ solutions which is less than $n$  . 
i am confused whats going on here . Can someone help me or give me some example . 
Thanks for help .

Comment: Separability only fails when you have an *irreducible* polynomial with repeated roots.

Comment: If $\,\operatorname{char} K=p\,$ and, for example, $\,n=p\Longrightarrow x^p-1=(x-1)^p\,$ ...

Comment: @JacobSchlather : Oh ok , that means here the polynomial is reducible.Separability is only about irreducible polynomial right ?

Comment: @DonAntonio : Ok , that means i just didn't look at the definition of separability carefully .

Comment: There are actually two slightly different definitions of 'separable polynomial'. The first one is: A polynomial over $K$ is separable if it has distinct roots in some algebraic closure of $K$. The second one says: A polynomial over $K$ is separable if each of its irreducible factors has no repeated roots. By the first definition $x^n - 1$ is not separable in general, by the second one it is.

Comment: @Gregor Right, but since Theorem is concerned about separability of a field extension, this is only going to fail if the second criterion you've given fails.

Comment: @Jacob: Just a tip - you should use [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), not MathJax, for formatting non-math stuff. I've edited your comment above.

Comment: Dear @Gregor, you are absolutely right, but  there is now a strong tendency to use the first definition, especially in commutative algebra and algebraic geometry, in which fields  I don't know  a single mathematician who uses the second one. Interestingly Bourbaki used the second definition in the first editions of His Algebra, but changed His mind in the later editions. To sum up,  I would strongly advise never  to consider $X^n \;(n\geq2)$ as a separable polynomial :-)

Comment: @ZevChonoles I thought about using the markdown, but I couldn't remember what the code was off the top of my head so I used mathjax out of laziness.

Comment: With regard to the ambiguity Georges talks about in the definition of "separable polynomial": he's right, but unfortunately most American textbooks prefer the second definition.  I also much prefer the first definition and justify it as follows: for any polynomial $f \in K[t]$ one can consider the algebra $K[t]/(f)$.  This is not a field extension of $K$ if $f$ isn't irreducible, but one can still study it.  One soon sees that it is a nice algebra iff $f$ has no repeated roots in $\overline{K}$...

Comment: Eventually one defines a **separable K-algebra** and then one has the nice fact that $K[t]/(f)$ is a separable algebra iff $f$ is a separable polynomial...according to the first definition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Let's actually record an answer!)

For any field $K$ and any positive integer $n$, the splitting field of $f = x^n-1$ is a separable field extension.  Because the polynomial $x^n-1$ is reducible for $n  > 1$ -- e.g. $x-1$ is a factor -- it may be cleanest not to reason with it directly.

Rather, the splitting field $L$ of $f$ is generated by adjoining to $F$ the $n$th roots of unity in an algebraic closure.  If we factor $n = \ell_1^{a_1} \cdots \ell_r^{a_r}$, we may separately adjoin the $\ell_i^{a_i}$ roots of unity: i.e., $L$ is the compositum of all these fields, so is separable iff each one is separable.

Case 1: $\ell$ is not equal to the characteristic of $K$.  Then the polynomial $x^{\ell_i^{a_i}} - 1$ has distinct roots in the algebraic closure, as can be checked by the usual Derivative Criterion (see e.g. $\S 6.1$ of [my field theory notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/FieldTheory.pdf)), so its splitting field gives a separable field extension.

Case 2: $\ell = p$ is the characteristic of $K$.  In this case there are no nontrivial $p$-power roots of unity in $\overline{K}$, so the extension in question is just $K$ itself, which is of course separable (even though the polynomial $x^{p^n}-1 = (x-1)^{p^n}$ is not a separable polynomial according to the first definition discussed in the comments following the question).